# In Adobe AIR, how can you get rid of the WindowedApplication's titleIcon?

Tags: windows, apache-flex, air, flex-spark

I've found how you're supposed to be able to change the image in the top-lefthand corner of a Spark WindowedApplication, but I don't seem to be able to just get rid of the thing altogether.  Setting it to null, trying to call removeElement on it, etc.  Isn't there some way, via Flex, to make Windows 7 and similar operating systems not show any sort of icon or dropdown menu on the upper-lefthand corner of an AIR app's window?  Thanks!

EDIT: This is kind of what I'm talking about.  I'm supposed to remove that icon over on the left, if it's reasonably possible.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking about something in the Flex app or the OS Chrome.  I think the chrome, but the question seems ambiguous.  A screenshot or further clarification may help here.

Comment: If your window uses the system chrome, there's nothing you can change about it. If it uses a custom chrome, you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: @Flextras An icon's been added.

Comment: @RIAstar What objects or properties would I need to look through the documentation of to set a custom chrome?  I'm looking, but I haven't found it so far.  Or do you just mean setting stuff like the title property of the spark.components.WindowedApplication?

Comment: https://www.google.be/search?q=air+spark+custom+chrome

Comment: I'll give you a +1 for adding the screenshot; it definitely clarifies what you're trying to do.  RIAStar has the proper answer here. You need to create custom Chrome to make this work.

Comment: Is there somewhere you can download the standard Windows 7 chrome so that you can edit it for something like this?  I'm not seeing anything so far.